# TFS 2017 - Variable substitution with double backslash in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to substitute a variable with double backslash using shell script task, my environment variable is configured to use double backslash.

When is substituted in bash script, the TFS puts only one backslash.

**Variable:**
[image]

**Substitution in script, I'm using double quotes because of white spaces in connection string:**

[image]

**Log of execution:**

[image]

I tried everything, put more backslashs, one quote around, but nothing works.

I appreciate a help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I solved it!!!

I just put the backslashes inside double quotes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need type `\\\\\\\\` in your variable:

```
CONNECTION_STRING: Data Source=192.168.2.227\\\\\\\\COMMERCE
```

Comment: Same result, doesn't matter how many backslashes I put, the result is always one backslash